# Scripts that get weeknumber, but changes to the next week every friday

Tags: javascript, function, date

I have a screen running and showing the jobs of the current week. 
I use this script to calculate current week:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}
```

But I would like it to show next week every friday. Is there an easy way to change the current script so it changes on friday instead? Maybe a way to get it to change at 10 am (my timezone - CEST)

All hints and pointers are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can simply increment reutrned value if today is `friday`.

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);        
    var weekNr = Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
    return this.getDay() == 5 ? weekNr + 1 : weekNr;
}
```

Keep in mind that `getDay()` returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date. So Sunday 0, Monday is 1 and Friday is 5. You can get more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Comment: Hi Lazarev! 
Thx, just what I was looking for, it seems to work great when i test with "2" for tuesday (today). Just to be absolutely sure I should set this to 5 when I want it to change on friday, right? (return this.getDay() == 5) ? :)

Comment: No, you should leave it 4. The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date. Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.

Comment: If Sunday is 0, Friday must be 5 then? :) 

Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, and Friday = 5 or have i lost my mind :)

Comment: Damn, you are right. Sorry, I was totaly confused :)

Comment: Great, i thought i had missed something. Thanks a lot for your help! :)
Would it be possible to check the time as well and first have it display the next week after 10 AM? :) Maybe with getTime? :)

Comment: Maybe I can just use getHours, I will play around with it :) thx :)

Comment: Logic is the same :) Also, keep in mind that if you are runing your code in the browser, it will get time from the computer. In its turn it can be different with the "real time". I think that it will be better to get time from the server, not from the client.

Comment: Great! Thx! 
Yeah offcourse. This has to run "locally" on 1 machine so i guess it doesn't matter! Thx again! :)